# How to remove extra unknown properties from object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering is it possible to remove extra unknown properties from object.

The exact problem which I am facing is that I know what fields I need in object, but I don't know what extra is coming and I need to remove those extras.

One option which comes in my mind is using hasOwnProperty function since we know what all properties we need.

Ex : Suppose we are getting below object :

```
{
    name: "Harry",
    age: 16,
    gender: "Male",
    Address: {
       prop1: "Hello",
       City: "LA"
    }
}
```

Now, we know that we need name, age, address and city in address beforehand but we are getting prop1 also as extra here and we don't know that it is exactly. It could be anything. We need to remove this prop1 from this object. This is just an example.

I think we need to use some recursive approach because the extra property could be at any place in the object.

Note: We have a list of properties which we need in advance.

Comment: What does your list of properties look like?

Comment: Take it anything, like set or array of properties

Comment: Yes but what does it look like? How does it represent nested properties?

Comment: No, just a Set with list of properties of object which we need. The object from which we need to delete the extra stuffs could be nested

Comment: Maybe you can use delete operator to remove certain properties from object more can be found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined a **schema** form of json (modify it as you want) and then I made a function that receives the json required to delete unwanted elements from it.

```js
const needAttribute =  {
 name: "Harry",
 age: 16,
 gender: "Male",
 Address: {
   City: "LA"
}
}

var json =
{
 name: "Harry",
 age: 16,
 gender: "Male",
 Address: {
   prop1: "Hello",
   City: "LA"
}
}
function getNeedAttributeFromJson(Myjson){
  for(var element in Myjson){
    if(needAttribute.hasOwnProperty(element)){
      if (typeof Myjson[element] === "object") {
        for(var subElement in Myjson[element]){
          if(!needAttribute[element].hasOwnProperty(subElement)){
            delete Myjson[element][subElement];
          }
        }
      }else{
        continue;
      }
    }else{
       delete Myjson[element];
    }
  }

  return Myjson;
}
console.log(getNeedAttributeFromJson(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash library.
REFERENCE URL - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit

```
const object =  {
 name: "Harry",
 age: 16,
 gender: "Male",
 Address: {
   prop1: "Hello",
   City: "LA"
}


object = _.omit(object.Address, 'prop1');

console.log(object);
```

Comment: This is possible only when I know that it's prop1 which I want to remove. The problem is I know only what I need to keep and not what I need to delete or remove